# How to use a Read Service properly in C#

Tags: c#

I have this Read Service method :

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetListQuery()
{
    return this._orderRepository.Table;
}
```

I'm calling this method like this :

```
  var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Order, ViewModelOrder_Order>();
                });

 List<ViewModelOrder_Order> orderList = this._orderReadService.GetListQuery()
                .Where(m => m.UserId == user.Id)
                .ProjectTo<ViewModelOrder_Order>(config)
                .ToList();
```

When I run this code, I get orderList as null. How can I fix this code? Thanks.

Here is my Order class :

```
public long Id { get; set; }

public string UserId { get; set; }

public string ProductId { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

Comment: this._orderReadService.GetListQuery()
                .Where(m => m.UserId == user.Id).ToList() has result?check without mapping

Comment: @M.Azad, ok let me check

Comment: @M.Azad It comes as null.

Answer (score 1):

if your search result has value you can change mapping like

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Order, ViewModelOrder_Order>();
            });
```

and use it like

```
List<Order> orderList = this._orderReadService.GetListQuery()
            .Where(m => m.UserId == user.Id)
            .ToList();
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var result=mapper .Map<List<ViewModelOrder_Order>>(orderList );
```

Comment: I get this error : 'List<Order>' does not contain a definition for 'ProjectTo' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.ProjectTo<IEnumerable<ViewModelOrder_Order>>(IQueryable, object, params Expression<Func<IEnumerable<ViewModelOrder_Order>, object>>[])' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

Comment: I changed it to this :               `List<ViewModelOrder_Order> orderList = this._orderReadService.GetListQuery()
            .Where(m => m.UserId == user.Id)
            .ProjectTo<IEnumerable<ViewModelOrder_Order>>(config)
            .ToList();`
And I get this error :
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Reveal.Presentation.Web.Areas.Manage.ViewModel.User.ViewModelOrder_Order>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Reveal.Presentation.Web.Areas.Manage.ViewModel.User.ViewModelOrder_Order>'

Comment: Your final code still gives error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Reveal.Domain.Payment.Entity.Order>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Reveal.Presentation.Web.Areas.Manage.ViewModel.User.ViewModelOrder_Order>'

Comment: @jason let me check

Comment: @jason I test my code and its worked for me.if you have any error add your ViewModelOrder_Order and Order  class code in your question

Comment: I posted my Order class, ViewModelOrder_Order is exactly the same. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @jason Are you define mapping for ApplicationUser  and  Product ?check sample without your virtual property